# properly not getting frequencies in numpy.fft

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have a signal in frequency domain.Then I took numpy.fft.ifft of signal.I got time domain signal.Again I took fft of same time signal properly I'm not getting negative and positive frequencies(Plot 3 in Figure).
[image]

```
     time       = np.arange(0, 10, .01)
     N          = len(time)
     signal_td  = np.cos(2.0*np.pi*2.0*time)
     signal_fd  = np.fft.fft(signal_td) 
     signal_fd2 = signal_fd[0:N/2]
     inv_td2    = np.fft.ifft(signal_fd2)
     fd2        = np.fft.fft(inv_td2)
```

Comment: How about posting the code you used to generate the plots?  Otherwise, it's hard to understand your problem.

Comment: @frank128791:I posted the codes

Answer (score 1):

General comment: I avoid using `time` as a variable name because `IPython` loads it as a "magic" command.

Something I find at times confusing about `matplotlib` is that when you `plot` a `complex` array, it actually plots the real part.  In the code snippet:

```
tt       = np.arange(0, 10, .01)
N          = len(tt)
signal_td  = np.cos(2.0*np.pi*2.0*tt)
signal_fd  = np.fft.fft(signal_td) 
signal_fd2 = signal_fd[0:N/2]
inv_td2    = np.fft.ifft(signal_fd2)
fd2        = np.fft.fft(inv_td2)
```

The following arrays have `dtype` of `float64`: `tt` and `signal_td`.  The others are `complex128`. The reason you only see one peak in `fd2` is because it is a transform of `exp(4j*np.pi*tt)` rather than `cos(4*np.pi*tt)`.

Comment: :Thanks frank.If I'm doing one more time of ifft and fft of signal_fd.I got two peaks which is same as singl_fd.Why fd2 transform exp()..instead of cos() here.                                                          `trans_1 =np.fft.ifft(signal_fd)`                               `trans_2 =np.fft.fft(trans_1)`

Comment: When you do the first transform, you get a complex valued array.  Removing just the negative frequencies in `signal_fd2` effectively removes the `sin()` terms.  If you have a look at the `.imag.std()`'s of these arrays, `signal_td` is real and `signal_td.imag.std()` is exactly zero.  For `signal_fd` and `signal_fd2` you get roundoff error only, and for `inv_td2` you get sqrt(2).  The imaginary part is there, but doesn't show up in the plot.  I hope that answers your question.

Comment: :Thank you very much frank.Now I understood.